# Send and receive response Rug.Osc

Tags: c#, osc

I use Rub Osc. Send its not problem, and receive not problem.

But i need sending OSC command and receive response. To Beringher x32.

Example, send "/ch/01/mix/on" and get 0 or 1.

```
    public double GetOSC(string IPOSC, int REMOTEPORTUSE, int LOCALPORTUSE, string ENVIOCOMANDO)
        {
    // Envio Comando 
            OscReceiver receiver;
            OscSender sender2;
        // Create the receiver
        using (receiver = new OscReceiver((int)LOCALPORTUSE))
        {              

            IPAddress address = IPAddress.Parse(IPOSC);



                using (sender2 = new OscSender(address, (int)LOCALPORTUSE, (int)REMOTEPORTUSE))
                {
                    // Connect the receiver
                    receiver.Connect();

                    //And Send
                    sender2.Connect();
                    sender2.Send(new OscMessage(ENVIOCOMANDO)); //"/ch/01/mix/on" 

                 // if we are in a state to recieve

                    if (receiver.State == OscSocketState.Connected )
                    {
                            // get the next message 
                            // this will block until one arrives or the socket is closed
                            OscPacket packet = receiver.Receive();

                            // Write the packet to the console

                            var output = Regex.Replace(packet.ToString().Split(',')[1], @"[^0-9.]", string.Empty);
                            double decim = double.Parse(output, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

                        return decim;

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return -1;

                    }

                }
        }

}
```

I launch all whit a thread. But if Threath sleep is minor to one second.. broken the application.
And appear the: System.ObjectDisposedException.

Any idea for send and recibe OSC well?

Answer (score 0):

"easy": You need to send a /remote OSC command every 10s, and the X32 will echo back to your applicaton all changes happening at the desk (fader movements, etc.). Refer to the documentation at https://sites.google.com/site/patrickmaillot/x32 for complete information and application examples (some simple, some not). 
-Patrick